# Where can I host oData web services in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I can create soap and wcf rest web services and put them in ISAPI folder to host them, and SharePoint host them for me.

Now I want to develop some custom oData services, how can I host them in SharePoint ? any tutorial would be helpful.